# Неоднородные определения

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Нужны ли запятые при неоднородных определениях, если одно из них прилагательное, а другое — сложная конструкция вроде:

*Мы увидели белую(,) с пятнами на спине и животе(,) собаку.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мы увидели белую, **с пятнами на спине и животе,** собаку.

Второе определение уточняет признак, названный первым определением.

**Пояснение**

Если второе определение является **несогласованным**, то оно может являться по отношению к первому определению однородным (отделяется запятой), неоднородным (нет запятой),  пояснительным или  уточняющим (выделяется запятыми).

Она сняла **толстую, с бахромой скатерть** и постелила другую (однородные, раскрывают общую тему, изображая общий вид предмета).

На стол поставили **синие с позолотой по краю** чашки (неоднородные, обозначают разные признаки).

Камнелом  расправил усы и бороду белыми, **в извёстке**, руками.  Я увидел на белой шапке кургана рдяно-жёлтую, **с огнистым отливом,** лису (уточняют или поясняют признак).

В некоторых случаях решение является авторским.