# Какие знаки нужны в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*Длинное почти до пят платье привлекало моё внимание.*

Answer (score 2):

*Длинное, **почти до пят**, платье привлекало моё внимание.*

Это уточняющее определение  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Сравнить: *Гаврик со всех сторон осмотрел маленького гимназиста **в длинной, до пят,** шинели* (Кат.);

Это стандартный (школьный)  вариант оформления, который применяется наиболее часто.

Примечание

В принципе возможны и другие варианты, теорию можно посмотреть в этой теме: [Неоднородные определения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428166/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Тогда это будет выглядеть так:

Неоднородные определения: ***Длинное почти до пят*** платье // привлекало моё внимание.

Однородные определения (интонация перечисления): ***Длинное, почти до пят*** платье // привлекало моё внимание.

Пример: *Все резко повернулись к дверям и с изумлением увидели тонкую фигурку Павлика в белой **длинной, почти до пят** рубашке.* [Григорий Адамов. Тайна двух океанов (1939)]